# Image won't change when replaced

Tags: php

I have a piece of code to upload a picture and save it in a folder and the path in a databaseand show it on the webpage. Funny enough, upon uploading the picture for the first time, the image will show on the webpage and with change when I upload a new picture. But when I close the page, reopen it another day and decide to change the picture, the one of the webpage won't change even if i refresh the page but the one in the folder will change.

Here's my code

```
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT Picture_HD FROM detailss WHERE Idn_nom = '$Indnum'";

require('connect.php');

$addr = "";
$addr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

if ($addr) {
    $locat = $addr->fetch_row();
    $locat = (string)$locat[0];
} else {
    $locat = "Pictures/default1.png";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo "<div id = 'Img'>";

echo "<img src = '" . $locat . "' alt = 'Passport picture/Headshot' style = 'width:80px; height:80px;'/>";

echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: is your browser caching it? Try Ctrl+F5 to force it to refresh from the server. P.S. I don't know if this code will be used on any kind of public website, but if it is, be aware that it's vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider using parameterised queries instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is caching the image.
If you want to prevent the browser to cache the image just add a random parameter at the end of the url.

```
echo "<img src = '" . $locat . "?t=" . time() . "' alt = 'Passport picture/Headshot' style = 'width:80px; height:80px;'/>";
```

Comment: Probably want `"?t="`

Comment: $locat is a path to a directory

Comment: Well seen AbraCadaver, i edited my post. @dnumbe10 yes but with your image file you will have something like : src = 'Pictures/default1.png?t=1486456086'

Comment: I don't have enough reputation. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If your image is changing in your folder but you are seeing the old one on the webpage it's likely a caching issue, clear your browser cache (ctrl+f5 plus this is kinda broken so doesn't always work - so best to go into browser settings to do it, or open a private window after ctrl+f5) and if not the clear server level cache.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to delete the existing image right before uploading the new one with the same file name

// define variables used for file name from session variable username the directory and extension by exploding the file name from the post method from a form with a metadata type

```
//set new file name to username from session variable
$filename = $_SESSION['username']
// set directory of files
$dir = "img/";
// set extension variable to file extension after posted from form
$ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['importimg']['name'])));
// new file upload name with existing extension
$upload_file = $dir . $filename . "." . $ext;

// delete file

// find all files with the same name any extension using variable        defined above etc .txt, .php, .gif, .jpg, etc. then delete it

foreach (glob("img/$filename.*") as $deletefile) {
  // unlink is used to delete the file and delete the cache of the file
unlink($deletefile);
}

// upload image 
// upload file with type posted from metadata in form and upload it         as your new file name using upload_file variable
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['importimg']['tmp_name'], $upload_file)) {
// successful upload of file add code for msg or sql query etc name to users table and redirect to profile page
echo "Successfully uploaded your file.";
} else {
// upload error show message
echo "There was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

Enjoy